# What's the best way to get/access data infos using nuxt and a personal backend API?

Tags: database, vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm working on a project and i'm using for the first time nuxt (first time vue too).

I have my own backend API which allow to create users and some others things.

So what's the best way to get/access data infos from my DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have axios installed in nuxt project, you can see below sample to retrieve api response and display.

```
<template>
 <div>
 {{api_response}}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
       async asyncData(app) {
     const response = await app.$axios.get(`/api/sample`)
    return { api_response: response.data}
  },
    data: () => ({

    }),


  }
</script>
```

but i think you need to learn more to implement api related activities, in that case read more from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So with axios, i just need to put the path of my local API to get the infos? ```const resp = await app.$axios.get('localhost:3080/getParamUser') ```something like that? And I will be able to get the userName by data using resp.data.username?         And I have a token store in the localStorage, it's not better to decode this token instead of the axios request?